Manipulating s-domain transfer function gives incorrect answer.
I am coming from an EE background but this question I believe is more relevant to this.
I have the following type-I second-order low pass filter. I expect there to be an integrator pole at the origin.

I found that, by writing the impedance of this circuit and doing the algebra. Depending on where I do my multiplication by s/s, I lose a pole.
Attempt 1

Attempt 2

Attempt 2 is correct as I verified by simulation. Attempt 1 isn't predicting the integrator pole at origin. Why?
I am pretty confident it is something to do with the s/s multiplication but not exactly how.

In the numerator of Attempt 1 you used the claim that,
$$(R_p + \frac{1}{s C_p}) (\frac{1}{s C_2}) s C_p C_2 = (s R_p C_2 C_p + C_2) (C_p)$$
But this is false. The $s C_p C_2$ either gets associated with the first product term, or the second, not both; formally, multiplication does not distribute over multiplication, it gets associated. So you should have written,
$$(R_p + \frac{1}{s C_p}) (\frac{1}{s C_2}) s C_p C_2 = (R_p + \frac{1}{s C_p}) C_p$$
The denominator is fine because you distributed the term over addition. This will force you to multiply numerator and denominator again by $s$ to rationalize thereby introducing the pole at the origin.
